# Group by is multiplying my number of rows

Tags: mysql, group-by, rows

I have a table with transfers (or trips, don't know what is the term) of patients. the transfer can be in ambulance, or in a car, it depends on the `movil` column.
I have to total the number of transfers grouped by day and type of `movil`.
Suppose this is my table:

```
day movil
1   M75
1   M76
1   M3
2   M6
2   M80
3   M8
3   M4
3   M83
3   M4
```

movil M71,M72,M75,M76,M77,M81,M82,M83 are ambulances, the rest are cars.
So I want to separate them between cars and ambulances.

Here's my query:

```
select 
    case when movil in ('M71','M72','M75','M76','M77','M81','M82','M83') then 'AMBULANCE' 
    else 'CAR' END as tipo,
    DAY(fecha) as day,
    COUNT(*) as total
from traslados
where YEAR(fecha) = '2016' and MONTH(fecha) = '07'
group by DAY(fecha),tipo
order by DAY(fecha)
```

So I should have 2 rows per day, one corresponding to the ambulances, and another corresponding to the cars. However, I'm getting 4 rows per day.
I don't understand why this happens.

Comment: can you post what the results look like?

Comment: show a snippet of the results...

Comment: I do not know how to show results because those data are fictitious.

Comment: but I can tell you , for every day, i'm getting 2 rows for ambulances , and 2 rows for cars. and i shoul have one and one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN movil IN ('M71',
                      'M72',
                      'M75',
                      'M76',
                      'M77',
                      'M81',
                      'M82',
                      'M83') THEN 'AMBULANCE'
       ELSE 'CAR'
   END AS tipo,
   DAY(fecha) AS DAY,
   COUNT(*) AS total FROM traslados WHERE YEAR(fecha) = '2016'  AND MONTH(fecha) = '07' GROUP BY DAY(fecha),
     CASE
         WHEN movil IN ('M71',
                        'M72',
                        'M75',
                        'M76',
                        'M77',
                        'M81',
                        'M82',
                        'M83') THEN 'AMBULANCE'
         ELSE 'CAR'
     END
 ORDER BY DAY(fecha)
```

Comment: incredible, that wah exactly what i was looking for. although I did not understand how it works !

Comment: you can't use an alias ('tipo') in a group by section

Comment: @martin.softpro The fact this change worked makes me wonder, is `traslados` a VIEW?

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, I just wrap the query in another query that doors the grouping, which save repeating lots of expressions, is easier to read and it portable:

```
select * from (
  select 
    case when movil in ('M71','M72','M75','M76','M77','M81','M82','M83') then 'AMBULANCE' 
      else 'CAR'end as tipo,
    DAY(fecha) as day
  from traslados
  where EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH from fecha) = '201607') x 
group by day, tipo
order by day
```

Notice also the use of EXTRACT to specify the year and month in one expression.